# ReactJS - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong with accessing and displaying part of my retrieved JSON object. I have the returned object stored in an array for each record returned and know how to traverse the JSON to access the right property/value in JS, however, I'm struggling to do the same within my ReactJS component. I'm still relatively new to React and can't seem to figure out the proper way traverse and display JSON properties and arrays. With my current setup I get `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {recordDateSlugEdit, ... If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.`  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Returned JSON Blob:**

```
[
  {
    "recordDateSlugEdit": "2017-08-17",
    "recordId": 119,
    "title": "POS Core Campaign CPL Rose 40%",
    "created_at": "2017-09-01T11:57:28.561Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-01T11:57:45.798Z",
    "user_id": 237,
    "category_id": 81,
    "app_user": {
      "userIdHash": "",
      "fullNameSlug": "Steve Matthews",
      "firstName": "Steve",
      "lastName": "Matthews"
    },
    "category": {
      "categoryIdHash": "",
      "categoryName": "Organic"
    },
    "record_comments": [
      {
        "createdAtDateSlug": "9\/1\/2017 8:13 AM",
        "commentId": 11,
        "comment": "Donec sem sapien, scelerisque fermentum interdum at, imperdiet vel dolor. Pellentesque fringilla elit eget risus maximus, aliquet luctus odio luctus. Sed pretium",
        "recordId": 119,
        "userId": 236,
        "created_at": "2017-09-01T12:13:23.557Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-01T12:13:23.557Z",
        "record_id": 119,
        "user_id": 236,
        "app_user": {
          "userIdHash": "oqX1p3EO5b",
          "fullNameSlug": "Brad Feld",
          "userId": 236,
          "firstName": "Brad",
          "lastName": "Feld",
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "recordDateSlugEdit": "2017-08-08",
    "recordId": 118,
    "title": "Added New CTA to Pricing Page",
    "user_id": 236,
    "category_id": 82,
    "app_user": {
      "userIdHash": "",
      "fullNameSlug": "Brad Feld",
      "firstName": "Brad",
      "lastName": "Feld",
    },
    "category": {
      "categoryIdHash": "",
      "categoryName": "Website"
    },
    "record_comments": [

    ]
  }
]
```

where I'm looking to access the properties found on the objects within the `record_comments` array located within each JSON record.

**Here is my component setup:**

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


//Comment Form
class CommentForm extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <form action="/app/record/comment" method="post">
            </form>
        )
    }
};

//Comments List
class Comments extends React.Component{

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {records: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                let records = data.map((record) => {
                    return(
                        <div key={record.record_comments.commentId}>
                            <li>{record.record_comments.comment}</li>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                this.setState({ records: data });
            })  
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>Comments List</h2>
            <ul>
                {this.state.records}
            </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

//Comment Container
export default class CommentBox extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="record-comment-form">
                <h1>Sweet it Worked</h1>
                <CommentForm />
                <hr />
                <Comments />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Its just a typho i guess. Your `setState` inside `fetchList` should be `this.setState({ records });`

Comment: Also one should not generate the JSX in fetch. You should do it in `render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only element that may be a child of `<ul>` is `<li>`.In your case you are using `div`. 
Also You need to change 
`setState({records:data})` to `setState({records})` or `setState({records:records})`

```
fetchList() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })  
        .then(data => {
            let records = data.map((record) => {
                return(

                        <li key={record.record_comments.commentId}>{record.record_comments.comment}</li>

                )
            })
            this.setState({ records:records});

        })  
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: The error is not because of this though, it is mainly because of state

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in

```
this.setState({ records: data });
```

data - is not a valid dom element.
Try to replace it with

```
this.setState({ records });
```

since records - seems to be an array of jsx elements.